# How can I compare two files and create another file that aren't in first file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, join

`file1` contains:

```
100
200
300
400
```

`file2` contains:

```
500
600
700
200
300
```

Expected output file will be:

```
500
600
700
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the output being sorted you can use [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm).

```
comm -13 <(sort /tmp/file1) <(sort /tmp/file2)
```

Output (implicitly sorted):

```
500
600
700
```

Answer (score 2):

With `join`:

```
join -j 1 -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Where:

- `-j` defines the join field
- `-v` to suppress joined lines

Or with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++} !a[$1]' file1 file2
```

- The first file is loaded in and array `a`
- and then when the second file is processed and if that value in `a` is not present, print the line